# Comparing Fields in Cognos BI and Returning Values Where They Don't Match

Tags: sql, filtering, business-intelligence, cognos-bi

I am trying to compare the data between two fields in Cognos BI that are coming from two different datasources. So, I ultimately want the dataset in which said fields are distinct, i.e they do not match.

The fields are, say "[Query1].[Organization ID]" and "[Query2].[CP_HomeOrg]". When running a joined query (using outer joins) , I see something like this:

Employee ID  | Organization ID |  CP_HomeOrg

1. 01        |    Value1       |      Value1
2. 02        |    Value2       |      Value2
3. .
4. .
5. .
6. 0k        |  (null)              | Valuek
7. 0k+1      |  Valuek+1           | Valuek+1
8. .
9. .

So, I proceed to write a filter as "[Organization] <> [Query2].[CP_HomeOrg]" but that does not work. It returns a blank dataset. For some reason it does not pick up the (null) values on the second column above.

I went ahead and did a cast( ) statement on the filter, casting as datatype varchar, but that does not help.

(Note: I checked the datatype in Cognos for the Organization ID and it is character of length 16.)

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: In a database you'd need to convert the NULL to something like a blank space before comparing it. To put it another way, Both of these expressions are false: `NULL = NULL`,  `NULL <> NULL`. So in SQL Server you would do something like `ISNULL([Organization ID],'') <> ISNULL([CP_HomeOrg],'')`. Have a look for a similar function in Cognos.

Comment: I've gone ahead and leveraged the coalesce( ) function in Cognos BI, which does the same thing and seems to be working. Thanks for the hint!